# JNI. управление памятью при возврате в java

Tags: java, c++, c, jni

Например если я выделяю память в c/c++ коде вот так и возвращаю это в java код, то что будет с памятью, она освободиться в java когда не будет уже нужна?

```
char *str = calloc ( 255, 1 );
return str;
```

Comment: А где java код?

Comment: @user7860670 я пока не помню как его надо писать. А что у вас вызывает это проблемы? Мне же нужна теория. Код java здесь вообще бессмысленен.

Comment: *"Код java здесь вообще бессмысленен."* - а без него нельзя сказать освободится память, или нет. Или это вопрос про то, не освободится ли она сама собой, без специальных действий на стороне java? Тогда ответ - нет, не освободится. И ненужность этого куска памяти отслеживаться тоже не будет.